# Is Vaadin-Time-Picker available? How to use poymer component in java?

Tags: polymer, vaadin

In my java (spring-boot and vaadin flow ) application, I want to add a time picker. But I did not find any time picker for java. There has a component for polymer([enter link description here](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadinvaadin-time-picker)).How can I use it? And is there any component then pls help me out.

tnx in advance.

Comment: It is a web component, so you can use these web components at your web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Java integration for the time picker is introduced in Vaadin 13, which was released as beta around one week ago and is scheduled to be final in about three weeks.